# Ampleness of the universal subbundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be a variety and $E$ an ample vector bundle on $X$. Let $G=G(r+1,E)$ be the Grassmann bundle over $X$ whose fiber over $x\in X$ is the Grassmannian of the $r+1$-dimensional subspaces of $E_x$. Let $U$ denote the universal subbundle on $G$. Under which hypothesis is the dual of $U$ ample on $G$?

Comment: I would assume never. If $U$ is ample on $G$, then its restriction to a fiber over $x\in X$ must be too, but this just takes you back to the universal subbundle of the Grasmmannian of $r+1$ dimensional subspaces in a vector space and thus can not be ample.

Comment: sorry...I had forgotten to write "the dual of"

Comment: I am interested in the dual of the universal subbundle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is essentially never true, again by restricting to a fiber over $x\in X$.  The problem is that (somewhat counterintuitively) the universal quotient bundle on $Gr(k,n)$ is not ample, and for the same reason, neither is the dual of the universal sub.  (Except of course when $k=1$!)  See Examples 6.1.5 and 6.1.6 in Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II*.